# A good TFT LCD for a project

Tags: lcd, display, tft

I am starting a project and I need a colour screen preferably clear to shuffle through images (think of it as the digital photo frames). However, I need something bigger than the usual screens, maybe 10".

After looking around for a while I didn't find anything fit into my project. What are the popular good LCDs which don't draw a lot of power and are fairly easy to interface?

Should I even go after TFT? Power is really important as my source is limited.

Comment: Can you quantify "limited"? Else electrophoretic!

Comment: What did you mean by "*colour screen **preferably clear** to shuffle through...*"?

Comment: Well I am looking for a LCD Screen not tri-colored LED screens. You know something like iPads screen which has a clear image. And I am just going to output JPG to it. That's it

Comment: Depending on the digital picture frame, some are simple composite in, some are rgb/vga in. Four out of Five I have seen are two parters, with a separate video/picture/processor and lcd board. You could always take one apart. Alternatively, you could get a portable DVD player screen.

Comment: There are a million cheap tablets / photo frames / monitors out there, what have you found that's closest and why can't you use it?

Answer (score 1):

" And I am just going to output JPG to it. "JPG is a file format not an electrical standard, if you want just a picture frame with some extra functionallity you can get a cheap tablet and save a lot of time and headaches. If you prefer the DIY route you can get a TFT + LVDS kit and a RaspberryPi.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the specific question asked. The OP clearly *can* get a TFT + LVDS kit, but the question takes that as the starting point, doesn't it?

Comment: it kind of is, I mean I am not building a picture frame, It's a mobile system that downloads data graphs from a webserver (in a JPEG format) and outputs to the LCD. Also it has to be low power so I don't want to use a big LCD for it. However, I like the rasberry idea very much so.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Definitely you can go for TFT. But remembered Response Times are the main concerns of TFT displays. Also check out the dot pitch measurement and ensure that your comparing like your buying more than one display. Keep the combination of high contrast and high brightness with low power consumption.